# elisp: call command on current file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to set a key in emacs to perform a shell command on the file in the buffer, and revert the buffer without prompting. The shell command is: `p4 edit 'currentfilename.ext'`

```
(global-set-key [\C-E] (funcall 'revert-buffer 1 1 1)) 
;; my attempt above to call revert-buffer with a non-nil 
;; argument (ignoring the shell command for now) -- get an init error:
;; Error in init file: error: "Buffer does not seem to be associated with any file"
```

Completely new to elisp. From the [emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Reverting.html), here is the definition of revert-buffer:

```
Command: revert-buffer &optional ignore-auto noconfirm preserve-modes
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to revert the buffer because it's already been edited, or because the shell command clobbers the contents of the buffer?

Comment: Because it changes the buffer to write instead of read-only, and adds it to version control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual error you're seeing is because you've specified the global-set-key incorrectly, namely the function call.  What you want is:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-e") '(lambda () (revert-buffer t t t)))
```

You had the `funcall` actually evaluating when your .emacs was loading, which is what caused the error.

Then, to get the whole thing, you can create a command like:

```
(defun call-something-on-current-buffers-file ()
  "run a command on the current file and revert the buffer"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command 
   (format "/home/tjackson/bin/dummy.sh %s" 
       (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
  (revert-buffer t t t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-e") 'call-something-on-current-buffers-file)
```

Obviously customize the command, and add error checking if you want.

Comment: You need to quote the filename for the shell somehow ... `comint-quote-filename` *looks* like it does the job but unfortunately it only does it if you're already in a shell buffer.  That's as far as I got.

Comment: @Zack `comint-quote-filename` call added.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get: `Symbol's function definition is void: comint-quote-filename`. I replaced it with `shell-quote-argument` and it worked great. Side note: the emacs manual stated: "Keys To Avoid: [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[letter]. In text terminals, it cannot distinguish shifted and unshifted versions of such combination. Works fine if you always use emacs in a GUI environment." So I changed it to <f5>, and it recognized the key.

Comment: @Jasie I knew there had to be a built-in quoting, I've updated the answer to use `shell-quote-argument`.  (to fix the void function definition error, you could just add `(require 'comint)`), but `shell-quote-argument` is better.

Comment: @TreyJackson this is very good, what do I need to do if I need the output to be poped up in a window that could be closed by pressing 'q' ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the minor mode "auto-revert-mode" is an option.
Just enable it on the current buffer:

```
M-x "auto-revert-mode"
```

and always ensure the buffer is saved, before executing an external command.

Comment: This is nice, but the default auto-revert-mode timing is 5 seconds (too slow). Then, if I changed it to 1 second, it would check every buffer every second, which is unnecessary.