# emacs extension to do system call, sleep, then reload buffer

Tags: emacs, lisp

I want to write an emacs extension such that when I do <kbd>M-x, b, k, e</kbd> the following things occur:

1. a system/shell call is executed where the last argument is the full path to the file of the buffer that is currently selected.
2. wait for the command to terminate or sleep for 3 seconds if it isn't possible to block for the return of a system call.
3. reload/restore the current buffer

How is this done?

Comment: A good way to start is learning Lisp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [elisp: call command on current file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697322/elisp-call-command-on-current-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close:

```
(defun bke ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf-name (buffer-file-name)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (shell-command (concat "your-command-here " buf-name) t))
    (revert-buffer t t t))
```

Comment: Perfect! I just bound it to a key sequence with `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c bke") 'bke )` and I'm off and running.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (at least two of three)

1) Shell call with last argument

```
(defun b ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat (read-string "$ ") " " buffer-file-name)))
```

2) I do not know, sorry.

3) Reload file.

```
(defun e ()
  (interactive)
  (revert-buffer t t t))
```

Comment: it looks like shell-command blocks, so it will inherently wait.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the key binding portion, this question is the same as: elisp: [call command on current file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697322/elisp-call-command-on-current-file).